# How to passing value of <input> into href of <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<input>` with type hidden to get value from a loop.

I want to pass values of `<input>` into attribute `href` of `<a>` tag.

My code:

```
<section id="block-text">
    <a class='moreInfo' target='_blank' href=""><button class='btnMoreInfo'>MORE INFO</button></a>
</section>

<section id="block-product">
    <input class="link_product_input" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item->link_product; ?>">
</section>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("moreInfo").href = $('.link_product_input').val();
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName): "_Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr` API:

```
$(".moreInfo").attr('href', $('.link_product_input').val() );
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("moreInfo")[0].href = $('.link_product_input').val()
```

Comment: `$(".moreInfo")`. You missing `.` before the class name. Thanks for your answer. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: I guess `attr()` is a method not a API, Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes.. correct.. i used api wording as jquery provide an iterface to us :).. it just personal perpsective view

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `id` to identify `a` tag instead of `class`.

Then use `document.getElementById()` to get this tag and assign value to `href`.

```
<section id="block-text">
    <a id="link-button" class='moreInfo' target='_blank' href=""><button class='btnMoreInfo'>MORE INFO</button></a>
</section>

<section id="block-product">
    <input class="link_product_input" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $item->link_product; ?>">
</section>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById("link-button").href = $('.link_product_input').val(); 
  }, false);
</script>
```